# How to access DOM structure of windows and iframes that are loaded from different domains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access data in iframe tag from different domains ([developers.google.com/my-business/content/tools/placeid-lookup](http://developers.google.com/my-business/content/tools/placeid-lookup))

but I have this problem error

> Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement
>   Blocked a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:8000" from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame.

how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: You cannot do this - it would be a *major* security flaw if it were possible.

Comment: Most likely you should use the proper Google API to request whatever information you are actually after here, instead of trying to parse this info out of a search result on a website ...

Comment: yes , i know this, but google filtrerd SBA , and not showing  them locations

Answer (score 0):

You can't *ideally* do this with JS because of the security issues it'd cause.
Maybe check how you can enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in your own local environment for development by changing the settings in your own browser, but this of course wouldn't be an option in production